# Why php command line can not get the ip address?

Tags: php

There are only one line in my /var/www/read.php ,and  build my lamp on local machine 127.0.0.1 .

```
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

When to input 127.0.0.1/read.php , i get the output

```
127.0.0.1
```

When to input command on console

```
php   /var/www/read.php
```

I ran into this message:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in /var/www/read.php on line 2
```

Why can't get the result of '127.0.0.1' ?

Comment: try `echo gethostbyname(gethostname());`

Comment: Who exactly is the remote party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] is given by the webserver and don't exists when the php script is called per command line.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no *remote address*. You're just executing a script on a command line, there's no TCP/IP involved, hence no "address" and most certainly no *remote address*. You need a web server involved to get any form of address from anywhere.