# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] no defined in call from Terminal

Tags: php, terminal, cron

I have some PHP scripts using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get IP of caller. It works fine. But today I tried to call one script from Terminal with the idea to test it before lets it run using CRON. The idea was to detect if the script was running really from the server and not from external call. 
But, when I call my script from Terminal I get :

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR

So it seems that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not defined when you run PHP Script from Terminal and so that the Terminal is not seen as a "client"?
Is it possible to get the IP of who exec the script, even if the call is made from CRON?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29034274/1640577

Comment: Thanks a lot Jithin I'd not found this before!